# Updating Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to update the object value using Javascript that is present inside the javascript function.
I tried the below

```
function update(){

var strength = 10;

nutrientsConsumed.g1.value = strength;

}
```

Need to Update the below **value**

```
var nutrientsConsumed = function()
    {

var g1 = new JustGage({
    id : "g1",
**value** : 0,
    min : 0,
    max : 100,
    title : "Protein",
    label : "",
    levelColorsGradient : false
});
```

Is the right way what I did or should I use different way.

Comment: "Is the right way" --- run it and see

Comment: I think from looking at your code that you are probably going to be best served by studying more on JavaScript objects and functions.  In your example, nutrientsConsumed is a reference to a function ... as such, you can't access "properties" because it doesn't have them ... it is a function.

Comment: I ran but I didnt get the result. Is the right way in sense whether that is the right syntax or not that way

Comment: "I ran but I didnt get the result" --- then it's not the right way. See, you could answer your question yourself.

Comment: @karthe It would probably be useful if you could explain a bit more of the background of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Kolban But you are correct that the way OP is using it will not work the way they think. So, actually, I just deleted the comment because it would probably add to confusion rather than help enlighten.

Comment: @Kolban I have a svg graph , so when I pass a value the graph will changes its value again if I pass another value same graph should get updates instead of that new graph is created. But, this is not what I am expecting

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code you are not actually updating the object but creating a new object. But if that is your goal you can pass it as a parameter:

```
var nutrientsConsumed = function(paramValue)
    {

var g1 = new JustGage({
    id : "g1",
**value** : paramValue,
    min : 0,
    max : 100,
    title : "Protein",
    label : "",
    levelColorsGradient : false
});

function update(){

var strength = 10;

nutrientsConsumed(strength);

}
```

Comment: I tried this mate already but when I pass value for second time another object is created

Comment: i need to populate  a graph when the object is updated. But when I pass the value second time new graph is created instead of old one.Your method param value is dynamic i will be changing it then and there so I need to update the same object always

Comment: This the code I have those graphs are loaded on application starup using windows.onload using a Jquery plugin called JUSTGUAGE